# onTouch listener for all the instances of a custom class

Tags: android, android-custom-view

i have a custom class that extends ImageView:

```
public class DraggableImageView extends android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatImageView {

    public DraggableImageView(Context context) {
        super(context);
    }


    @Override
    protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
        super.onDraw(canvas);
    }
}
```

I would like to create an onTouchListener in the custom class, so that each instance would act in the same way.

I also would like to know how to refer to the instance from the class itself, for example, if I have a DraggableImageView instance and I call its custom method "ciccio", how can ciccio change some parameters of the instance (like position or source of the image)?

Thanks in advance for any help,

Lorenzo

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To add touch listener in your custom view, you can simply override the method `onTouchEvent`.

Another way would be to set new `OnTouchListener` in the constructor, but overriding `onTouchEvent` is recommended.

Not sure what you mean by referring the instance from class itself. It is a very basic thing. You can use them directly or by using '`this`' keyword. For eg. `this.getHeight()`, `this.setLayoutParams(/*params*/)`, etc.

Comment: Thanks, but how can I refer to the instance in onTouchEvent? For example, as I said, to know the position of the ImageView and so on?

Yes, I tried it, but I think it thought that "this" was the touchListener

Comment: UPDATE
Forget what I said about the reference to itself, I was definitely writing something wrong, because I tried again as you said and it worked :)

Comment: Happy to help. :)